# Fundamental questions on "The shortest distance between two points is a straight line."

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-history, axiomatic-geometry

In retrospective of history of mathematics, I am trying to reconstruct the answers to following fundamental questions:

1. Who proved first in a certain geometry that
   *"The shortest distance between two points is a straight line."*? Please provide proof or give precise reference thereto.
2. Is the statement *"The shortest distance between two points is a straight line."* within an Euclidean geometry an *axiom* or a *theorem*?
3. Does Euclidean geometry (and/or any other geometry) define (per axiom), what a *"point"*, what a *"line"*, and what a *"straight line"* to be?

*Remarks:*

- The statement above could have been of course formulated over time in different ways, for instance instead of the notion *"distance"* I also recognized *"path"* and *"curve"*.
- Precise references, explanation and proofs needed, *non-trivial answers appreciated*.

*Thank you in advance for your support.*

Comment: I wonder if this question is more suited to https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StinkingBishop Indeed, it would be interesting to set the first question also to there. However, I really aim at focusing on math and non-trivial answers. I know setting such questions in other forums rather would end up in foggy narratives and philosophical debates. The questions here are pure of mathematics and mathematical formalism. Please kindly be focused.

Comment: Triangular inequality (proved by Euclid in the Elements) is the first theorem that comes to mind.

Comment: Statement (1) isn't true in the taxi cab metric.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in the history side of things, but here is a sort of intuitive proof: https://ibb.co/K9Jjy2S

Comment: In the original Euclid's Greek text there is no "distance".

Comment: "point" and "line" are undefined in the modern sense, because the [definitions provided](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html#defs) are quite useless and puzzling. According to scholars, they are probably later additions to the original text.

Answer (score 1):

In his *On the Sphere and Cylinder I*, Archimedes gives some definitions, and then some assumptions.  His first assumption reads (translated into English):

> "*Of all lines which have the same extremities the straight line is the least.*" [translated by Thomas Heath, emphasis as given by Heath]

For "extremities," read "endpoints"; for "least," read "shortest."  The notion that a straight line is the shortest distance between two points is often ascribed to Archimedes on the basis of this assumption.  Given that, I suppose we might call this an axiom, rather than a theorem, and therefore it would not admit of a proof.

---

In Euclidean geometry, terms such as "point" and "line" are often called "undefined," meaning that they are defined by their behavior in the axioms, rather than explicitly in some kind of glossary.

The idea of a "*straight* line" (as opposed to a line that is not straight) on the other hand, appears to me to have been assumed as obvious by many of the ancient Greeks.  For instance, Archimedes (in the same work) uses "straight line" in a few of the definitions, but nowhere defines it or states what conditions it must satisfy.  Euclid says in Definition 4 of his *Elements* that

> "A *straight line* is a line which lies evenly with the points on itself." [again, translated by Thomas Heath]

I think you'll agree that this is not exactly satisfying as a definition.

Comment: I think Archimedes assumption CAN be proved in the framework of Euclidean geometry, if the length of a curve is defined (as it was customary) as the limit of the length of a polygonal. By triangular inequality one can easily show that segment $AB$ is shorter than any other polygonal connecting $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: That's a fair point—do you have any background on when and where such a definition might have been made?

Comment: I don't know of any explicit case. But just think of the way Archimedes approximated the length of a circle by inscribed and circumscribed polygons to see that this was quite common.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: Oh, I agree.  I don't think they were in any confusion about the *practical* considerations behind measuring arc lengths (at least for "well-behaved" curves), but they probably did not have the same rigorous perspective that modern mathematics has.

Comment: That's true, of course. But I think Archimedes (or some other ancient geometer) could have proved that assumption, starting with some definition for the length of a curve, if he thought that was worthwhile. The tools for doing that were all there.