# Why is the shortest path diagonal?

Tags: geometry

I've been pondering this concept for around a day now and can't come up with an answer myself. I was wondering why the diagonal path is the shortest path and not horizontal + vertical. The thing that's throwing me off is that if you imagine an infinitesimally small step in the x-direction and then imagining an infinitesimally small step in the y-direction and then do this an infinite amount of times then it would seem like the same distance as the diagonal path.

I know that this can't be true but some of you might be able to provide an answer to why this is.

Edit:
Some didn't understand what I was asking for which is on me as I didn't explain properly. My question was that if you have a point a = (0, 0) and a point b = (x, y) why is the shortest path from a to b the diagonal or sqrt(x^2 + y^2). If you imagine taking an infinitesimally small step in the direction of x and then an infinitesimally step in the direction of y that an infinite number of times it should form a straight line. This was proven false by the comment below.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4) may help.

Comment: I feel strongly that questions need to explain what they are about, completely unlike this one.  If you have to guess what the question is about, it probably ought to be closed.

Comment: In Manhattan, your reasoning makes (see [taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)). On a boat in the middle of the ocean, well Pythagoras, is happy to prove you wrong, because you can go in *continuously* many direction.

Comment: If you add up all the infinitesimal steps, that is if you integrate you get the complete way in y and in x direction, Maybe just take first 4 steps, than 8 and see that it is still the same, than divide any step in two and sie it gets not shorter

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but as David pointed out, it's been asked here before.

Comment: No, it was a *terrible* question (before it was revised), because it never stated what distance the question was asking about. That is something that even an 8th grader (in the U.S., about a 13-year-old) should comprehend.

Comment: The edited question draws the wrong conclusion. In fact, alternating n horizontal steps of length x/n with n vertical steps of length y/n **does**, as n → ∞, approach the diagonal line in a very straightforward way.  What is **not** true is that the *length* of that zigzag line approaches the *length* of the diagonal line as n → ∞.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest path between two points in the plane is a segment of the **straight line** between them. This line segment naturally forms a diagonal of a rectangle with those two points as its vertices. So the more pressing question is, why is a straight line the shortest path? (And why do we measure distance the way we do [ie, with "Euclidean distance"]?)

The fact that straight lines minimize distance was observed by [Archimedes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4306563/161490). You could loosely justify it by observing that any path that deviates from a straight line will have to take a detour through a third point; rather than running from $A$ to $B$, the path would run from $A$ to $X$ to $B$. And that detour must bulge the path out and form a shape roughly akin to a triangle. But the sum of two sides of a triangle should not be longer than the third side, due to the ["triangle inequality"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html), which we ordinarily take as a given in geometry, or which we can [prove algebraically](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangle_Inequality/Real_Numbers#Proof_1) (using some understanding of vectors). So the shortest path should follow only one edge and be a straight line. But perhaps appealing to the triangle inequality is just begging your original question. So we could instead prove it with more rigour using more advanced techniques from calculus of variations. See for example [this proof](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node86.html) and [this MSE page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833434/why-is-a-straight-line-the-shortest-distance-between-two-points?rq=1).

As to why we use use Euclidean distance, a big factor is rotation invariance. Physically, we expect that taking one step, we will move exactly as far, regardless of the angle we're facing. A one meter step north should go equally far as a one meter step northeast. This property holds for the Euclidean distance but *not* for the taxicab metric (ie, horizontal plus vertical).

> The thing that's throwing me off is that if you imagine an infinitesimally small step in the x-direction and then imagining an infinitesimally small step in the y-direction and then do this an infinite amount of times then it would seem like the same distance as the diagonal path.

The fallacy here is that you are failing to properly apply concepts of convergence (ie, a strict mathematical sense of "turning into [something]"). In particular, convergence in path does **not** necessarily mean convergence in path *length*. [This "$\pi=4$" question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4) linked in the comments is a good place to see how this could lead you astray. Observe that the total length depends both on the size of the summands *and also how many* of the summands there are. The smaller the pieces of your curve become, the more pieces you get! These rates may be matching and balance out, so the total distance of the curve may never change. Moral of the story: you should actually compute the distance of the curve rather than appealing to blind intuition.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually asking why in a right angled triangle, hypotenuse is less than the sum of other two sides, as **horizontal+vertical** means a pair of perpendicular lines so the the diagonal naturally implies the hypotenuse.

Let the length of the hypotenuse be $b$ and the length of other two sides be $a$ and $c$.

Now, $$(a+c)^2-b^2=a^2+c^2+2ac-b^2$$
But using Pythagoras theorem, $a^2+c^2=b^2$ or $$(a+c)^2-b^2=2ac>0$$

Since $$(a+c)^2-b^2>0$$ $$\implies (a+c)^2>b^2$$ Taking square root on both sides implies, $$a+c>b$$

**Edit**

The diagonal is absolutely a shorter distance than horizontal+vertical but not the shortest distance.

For the shortest distance, assume a cardboard cut in the shape of a right angled triangle. Then to go from one end of the hypotenuse to another, **bend the cardboard in such a way that those two ends meet**. You went to your destination without even traveling.

Comment: How did you figure out what was being asked by the post? Did @CuriousSoul email you separately?

Comment: @JohnDouma is that a sarcasm

Comment: Not at all. "I've been pondering this concept for around a day now and can't come up with an answer myself. I was wondering why the diagonal path is the shortest path and not horizontal + vertical." How did you determine that this applied to the pythagorean theorem? What concept is he talking about? By the way, sarcasm is not countable so you would say "Is that sarcasm?", not "Is that a sarcasm?".

Comment: @JohnDouma It was just my intuition... nothing more...and yeah my grammer is not so good

Comment: Likewise your spelling.

Comment: @DanAsimov which spelling?

Comment: If you look up the words (from your comment above mine) in a dictionary, that will give you valuable experience using a dictionary.

Comment: @DanAsimov I still can't figure it out

Comment: @DanAsimov I'm sorry Dan but what exactly are you seeking when partaking in this discussion except to demean others? It is fine to criticize but you're obviously not on here to help but rather to feel better about yourself or to fuel your own ego. Please check yourself and better your manners because I'd bet that you don't act this way in real life so why would you do so online?

Comment: CuriousSoul — From my point of view, yours is the only comment that is demeaning. "Give a man a fish and he eats for one day; teach a man to fish and he eats for his whole life."

Comment: @DanAsimov can u actually tell which spelling was wrong instead of giving mean remarks

Comment: @DanAsimov Yes, teaching is encouraged but berating is not. You only have a single comment about the actual topic at hand out of 5 comments (not counting your last reply) so what are you teaching, how to feed one's superiority complex perhaps? I have no other conclusion but to say that you're a troll.